# Requiero realizar una condición para entregar una alerta en caso de cumplir 2 como mínimo

Tags: javascript, html

soy nuevo en esto y trabajo en una pequeña empresa donde se pide realizar un formulario de síntomas covid según la resolución 43 exenta del ministerio de salud. Básicamente necesito que las personas al ingresar al trabajo completen el formulario y se les indique si corresponde a síntomas "cardinales" o "no cardinales" luego ingresar los datos a una base de datos y avisar mediante correo electrónico a su jefe los que tienen sintoma, esos 2 últimos pasos lo voy averiguar mas adelante.
El problema que tengo actualmente es que no logro crear una condición en javascript que evalué si una persona tiene mas de un síntoma cardinal.

**Nota:** El formulario lo tengo paralelamente por mientras en google forms, pero no se como se puede agregar una alerta que aparezca después de apretar el botón enviar para indicar de inmediato si tiene síntoma por lo que ahora lo estoy pasando todo a uno propio.

```
<script>
    
function sintomas(){
    let cfiebre = fingreso.fiebre.value
    let cpgusto = fingreso.pgusto.value
    let cpolfato = fingreso.polfato.value
    let ctos = fingreso.tos.value
    let cdisnea = fingreso.disnea.value
    
    /*if(cfiebre=="si" || cpgusto=="si" || cpolfato=="si"){
        alert("Persona Cardinal")
    }*/
    
    let contador = 0
    if (cfiebre=="si") contador += 15;
    if (cpgusto=="si") contador += 15;
    if (cpolfato=="si") contador += 15;
    if (ctos=="si")     contador += 1;
    if (disnea=="si")   contador += 1;
    
    if (contador >= 15) {
        alert("Cardinal");
        alert(contador);
    }
    if (contador >= 2 || <15){
        alert("No Cardinal");
    }
    else{
        alert("Excelente no tiene sintomas");
    }
} 

</script>
<H2>Formulario</H2>
<FORM name="fingreso" action="" method="POST">
<label form="nombre">Nombre: </label>
<INPUT name="nombre" type="text">
<br><br>

<label form="nombre">Codigo: </label>
<INPUT name="nombre" type="text">
<br><br>

<h3>Fiebre (Mayor a 37,8 °C): </h3>
<input type="radio" name="fiebre" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="fiebre" value="no" checked> No
<br><br>

<h3>Tos: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="tos" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="tos" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Disnea o dificultad respiratoria: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="disnea" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="disnea" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Congestión nasal: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="congestion" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="congestion" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Taquipnea o aumento de la frecuencia respiratoria: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="taquipnea" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="taquipnea" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Odinofagia o dolor de garganta al comer o tragar: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="odinofagiar" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="odinofagiar" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Mialgias o dolores musculares: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="mialgias" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mialgias" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Debilidad general o fatiga: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="fatiga" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="fatiga" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Dolor torácico: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="dolor" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="dolor" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Calofríos: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="calofrio" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="calofrio" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Cefalea o dolor de cabeza: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="cefalea" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="cefalea" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Diarrea: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="diarrea" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="diarrea" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Anorexia o náuseas o vómitos: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="anorexia" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="anorexia" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Pérdida brusca del olfato o anosmia: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="polfato" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="polfato" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Pérdida brusca del gusto o ageusia: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="pgusto" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="pgusto" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="sintomas();">

</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para contarlos, puedes simplemente ir sumando 1 por cada *sintoma* que si tenga.

Basado en tu código de ejemplo, podría ser algo como:

```js
function sintomas(){
    let cfiebre = fingreso.fiebre.value
    let cpgusto = fingreso.pgusto.value
    let cpolfato = fingreso.polfato.value
    
    if(cfiebre=="si" || cpgusto=="si" || cpolfato=="si") 
        alert("Persona Cardinal")
    else
        alert("Excelente, no tienes sintomas")

    let contador = 0
    if (cfiebre=="si") contador += 1;
    if (cpgusto=="si") contador += 1;
    if (cpolfato=="si") contador += 1;
    
    if (contador >= 2) {
      alert("tiene 2 o más síntomas cardinales a la vez");
    }
    
}
```

```html
<H2>Formulario</H2>
<FORM name="fingreso" action="" method="POST">
<label form="nombre">Nombre: </label>
<INPUT name="nombre" type="text">
<br><br>

<label form="nombre">Codigo: </label>
<INPUT name="nombre" type="text">
<br><br>

<h3>Fiebre (Mayor a 37,8 °C): </h3>
<input type="radio" name="fiebre" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="fiebre" value="no" checked> No
<br><br>

<h3>Tos: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="tos" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="tos" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Disnea o dificultad respiratoria: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="disnea" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="disnea" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Congestión nasal: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="congestion" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="congestion" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Taquipnea o aumento de la frecuencia respiratoria: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="taquipnea" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="taquipnea" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Odinofagia o dolor de garganta al comer o tragar: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="odinofagiar" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="odinofagiar" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Mialgias o dolores musculares: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="mialgias" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mialgias" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Debilidad general o fatiga: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="fatiga" value="si"> Si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="fatiga" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Dolor torácico: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="dolor" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="dolor" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Calofríos: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="calofrio" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="calofrio" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Cefalea o dolor de cabeza: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="cefalea" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="cefalea" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Diarrea: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="diarrea" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="diarrea" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Anorexia o náuseas o vómitos: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="anorexia" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="anorexia" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Pérdida brusca del olfato o anosmia: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="polfato" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="polfato" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<h3>Pérdida brusca del gusto o ageusia: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="pgusto" value="si"> si
<br>
<input type="radio" name="pgusto" value="no" checked> no
<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="sintomas();">

</FORM>
```

Además de la *solución* a tu problema, he agregado `let` para declarar las variables que ya tenías, además de la nueva `contador`, donde se va acumulando cuantos síntomas *cardinales* están marcados y finalmente decir que no he publicado solamente el javascript para que puedas *probar* aquí mismo la solución dando clic en el botón *ejecutar*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, he logrado solucionarlo en parte gracias a lo que me indicaste, pero me olvide indicar que 3 síntomas específicos (fiebre, gusto, olfato) se consideran cardinales, la suma de 2 del resto de los síntomas se consideran no cardinal y no tener ningún síntoma se considera sin síntomas.

con el siguiente codigo n puedo lograr lo que

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí por una búsqueda a identificar que la respuesta fue de ayuda. Utiliza esta técnica también cuando hagas investigaciones y caigas a StackOverflow, pues fácilmente puedes identificar, cuando hay varias respuestas, cuál es la que le ha servido a quien planteó originalmente el problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].

Comment: Hola acabo de actualizar el código en la primera pregunta ya que no puedo lograr hacer que según los datos ingresados la persona quede en una de 3 categorías:

**Cardinal=** 3 síntomas específicos (fiebre, gusto, olfato)
**No cardinal=**  la suma de 2 del resto de los síntomas
**Sin síntomas=** ningún síntoma marcado.

Me había olvidado especificar eso anteriormente, disculpa.
Creo que se debe a un error de sintaxis en el segundo if

Comment: Editar una pregunta luego que has recibido una respuesta _correcta_ para dicha pregunta, me parece descortés, pues dejas sin validez mi respuesta. Por otro lado, el trabajo es tuyo, con las ideas que te he dado, si te esfuerzas por entenderlas, podrías escribir la solución completa por ti mismo, ¿no crees?

Comment: Por otro lado, si tienes una nueva pregunta, cosa que es normal que suceda cuando avanzas, pues, StackOverflow te permite escribir una nueva pregunta, mejor si es un [mcve].

Comment: ok, estimado la verdad es que no sabia lo que mencionas sobre la edición de la primera pregunta, lo hice porque en este cuadro al comentar código indica que es mucho texto. Entonces pensé que la mejor forma era editar en el primer cuadro. Y es obvio que he estado tratando de entenderlo si he mirado varios video antes de consultar. Para no molestar por este medio.